# Temporarily storing multiple values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, t-sql, plsql, temporary-objects

I need a way to *temporarily* store and use multiple values returned from an Oracle query.  In SQL Server, I stored my values in a temp table, did my work, then dropped the table.  I'm discovering the Oracle equivalent isn't as clear cut.

Here's a SQL Server example of what I'm trying to do:

```
select id into #temp from SomeTable where SomeColumn = 'Some Value'
   :
(do whatever I need to do with #temp data)
   :
drop table #temp
```

I can code my way around SQL Server pretty well, but am almost clueless when it comes to Oracle syntax.  I've been reading various Oracle references, and they haven't been very helpful.  I did read that Oracle temp tables work differently than SQL, and are often not recommended.

I'm looking into the temp table route, but if there's a better way to do this that doesn't use temp tables, I'm all ears.  Anyone know a better way to do this in Oracle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing with `#temp` in your procedure and why are you temporarily materializing the data?  That will influence how best to translate your code.  See, for example, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34279/temporary-table-inside-procedure-oracle/34322#34322

Comment: Long story short: I need to swap values in a column.  For example, I have values SomeValue1 and SomeValue2 in SomeColumn.  I need to swap SomeValue1 for SomeValue2 and vice versa.  I need the #temp values (I actually have two of these) to keep track of what IDs are storing what values.

Comment: I did some reading on collections.  That definitely has potential.

Comment: Ugh.  As usual, I'm overthinking this (again!).  I came up with a simpler solution that doesn't require temp tables or collections.  That's what I get for doing this late on a Friday afternoon!  At least I learned something new (I was not familiar with collections before I asked this question).  Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

As with many things, that depends. It depends on how much data you'll be retrieving and how you want to use it. If you don't have too much data to work with ("too much" meaning, oh, say, more than a couple thousand rows) and you want to manipulate the data procedurally, i.e. in a PL/SQL procedure or script, AND you don't want to access it using DML, i.e. you don't want to say something like `SELECT * FROM your_temp_data...` than loading the data into a PL/SQL collection, as @EgorSkriptunoff mentions above, might be a workable solution.

However, if the temp data is large (more than a couple thousand rows) and/or you need to be able to do something like `SELECT * FROM your_temp_data...` then your best bet it to use Oracle's Global Temp Tables. A GTT is a table which is used to hold data which should only last as long as either a single transaction or a complete session (i.e. as long as you're attached to the database). [Documentation here](https://class.coursera.org/medievalspain-001/human_grading) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#i2153132), and another write-up on them [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables.php).

Share and enjoy.